# Debug.DrawLine not showing in the GameView

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 2D Unity app and I'm encountering some weird behavior.

This code works just fine.

```
Debug.DrawLine(button1.transform.position, button2.transform.position, Color.green);
```

When I run the app, I see a green line in the Scene view.

But nothing appears in the Game view when I have the following line.

```
Physics2D.Linecast(button1.transform.position, button2.transform.position);
```

I'm confused as to how Unity is able to draw a line between these two buttons, but for some reason, it's just not doing it in the Game view.

Any idea how I'd troubleshoot this?

Comment: Er, `Linecast()` doesn't draw a visible line - it just checks along a line for intersections with any physics colliders. If you want to draw a visible line, create a LineRenderer or use the `GL` library.

Comment: AHA!  Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Just line [Serlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819071/unity-debug-drawline-works-but-physics2d-linecast-doesnt#comment72749890_42819071) said, `Physics2D.Linecast` is not used to draw a line but to detect if there is an object in the middle of two objects with raycast. It has nothing to do with drawing lines.

As you already know, `Debug.DrawLine` will only work in the Scene view unless Gizmos is enabled. You can just [`LineRenderer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.html) or the [`GL`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.html) functions to draw lines which will work without enabling Gizmos and will also work in a build.

Here is a helper class for drawing line in the Game and Scene view.

```
public struct LineDrawer
{
    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    private float lineSize;

    public LineDrawer(float lineSize = 0.2f)
    {
        GameObject lineObj = new GameObject("LineObj");
        lineRenderer = lineObj.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        //Particles/Additive
        lineRenderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Hidden/Internal-Colored"));

        this.lineSize = lineSize;
    }

    private void init(float lineSize = 0.2f)
    {
        if (lineRenderer == null)
        {
            GameObject lineObj = new GameObject("LineObj");
            lineRenderer = lineObj.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
            //Particles/Additive
            lineRenderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Hidden/Internal-Colored"));

            this.lineSize = lineSize;
        }
    }

    //Draws lines through the provided vertices
    public void DrawLineInGameView(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, Color color)
    {
        if (lineRenderer == null)
        {
            init(0.2f);
        }

        //Set color
        lineRenderer.startColor = color;
        lineRenderer.endColor = color;

        //Set width
        lineRenderer.startWidth = lineSize;
        lineRenderer.endWidth = lineSize;

        //Set line count which is 2
        lineRenderer.positionCount = 2;

        //Set the postion of both two lines
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, start);
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, end);
    }

    public void Destroy()
    {
        if (lineRenderer != null)
        {
            UnityEngine.Object.Destroy(lineRenderer.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
LineDrawer lineDrawer;

void Start()
{
    lineDrawer = new LineDrawer();
}

void Update()
{
    lineDrawer.DrawLineInGameView(Vector3.zero, new Vector3(0, 40, 0f), Color.blue);
}
```

When done, you can call `lineDrawer.Destroy();`.

Comment: When I use Debug.DrawLine, I see them in game view as long as gizmos are turned on in game view.

Comment: @Adrian That's true. I added that to the answer. No one like to see Gizmo lines to be all over the Game View Screen and Debug.DrawLine does not work in a build.

Comment: Oh it looks insane, but sometimes it's very useful for troubleshooting.

Comment: Yes it useful for troubleshooting in Editor only but not when you want to troubleshoot lines on the target device. For example Android screen edge detection.

Comment: Not all Unity applications are to be released as games so it's still a shame that Debug.DrawRay() does not work in Release builds. I could use it.

Answer (score 1):

Debug.DrawLine renders a line gizmo into the Scene View.

If you want a line rendered into the Game View, use a Line Renderer Component.

[Line Renderer Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html)