# Draw line in GameView

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.ThirdPerson;

public class WayPoints : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] waypoints;
    public Transform target;
    public float moveSpeed = 10f;
    public float moveSpeed1 = 10f;
    public float slowDownSpeed = 3f;
    public float reverseSlowDownSpeed = 3f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 1f;
    private Transform myTransform;
    private int targetsIndex = 0;
    private Vector3 originalPosition;
    private GameObject[] robots;

    public Transform reverseTarget;
    private int reverseTargetsIndex = 0;
    private Vector3 reverseOriginalPosition;
    private Animations anims;

    public bool random = false;

    void Awake()
    {
        myTransform = transform;
    }
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        anims = GetComponent<Animations>();
        waypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ClonedObject");
        robots = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Robots");

        foreach(GameObject go in waypoints)
        {
            go.isStatic = true;
        }
        UnityEditor.AI.NavMeshBuilder.BuildNavMesh();

        //AddColliderToWaypoints();
        originalPosition = robots[0].transform.position;
        reverseOriginalPosition = robots[1].transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (MyCommands.walkbetweenwaypoints == true)
        {
            anims.PlayState(Animations.AnimatorStates.RUN);
            WayPointsAI();
            ReverseWayPointsAI();
        }

        DrawLinesInScene();
    }

    private void WayPointsAI()
    {
        if (targetsIndex == waypoints.Length)
            targetsIndex = 0;
        target = waypoints[targetsIndex].transform;
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(robots[0].transform.position, target.transform.position);
        robots[0].transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(robots[0].transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - robots[0].transform.position), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        //move towards the player
        if (distance < 30)
        {
            robots[0].transform.position += robots[0].transform.forward * slowDownSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            robots[0].transform.position += robots[0].transform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (distance < 2)
        {
            targetsIndex++;
        }
    }

    private void ReverseWayPointsAI()
    {
        if (reverseTargetsIndex == 0)
            reverseTargetsIndex = waypoints.Length -1;
        reverseTarget = waypoints[reverseTargetsIndex].transform;
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(robots[1].transform.position, reverseTarget.transform.position);
        robots[1].transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(robots[1].transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(reverseTarget.position - robots[1].transform.position), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        //move towards the player
        if (distance < 30)
        {
            robots[1].transform.position += robots[1].transform.forward * reverseSlowDownSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            robots[1].transform.position += robots[1].transform.forward * moveSpeed1 * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (distance < 2)
        {
            reverseTargetsIndex--;
        }
    }

    void RandomWayPointsAI()
    {
        if (random == true)
        {
            int index = Random.Range(0, waypoints.Length);
            target = waypoints[index].transform;
        }
    }

    void DrawLinesInScene()
    {
        // draw lines between each checkpoint //
        for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(waypoints[i].transform.position, waypoints[i + 1].transform.position, Color.blue);
        }

        // draw a line between the original transform start position 
        // and the current transform position //
        Debug.DrawLine(originalPosition, robots[0].transform.position, Color.red);
        Debug.DrawLine(reverseOriginalPosition, robots[1].transform.position, Color.red);

        // draw a line between current transform position and the next waypoint target
        // each time reached a waypoint.
        if (target != null)
            Debug.DrawLine(target.transform.position, robots[0].transform.position, Color.green);
        if (reverseTarget != null)
            Debug.DrawLine(reverseTarget.transform.position, robots[1].transform.position, Color.green);
    }

    void AddColliderToWaypoints()
    {
        foreach (GameObject go in waypoints)
        {
            SphereCollider sc = go.AddComponent<SphereCollider>() as SphereCollider;
            sc.isTrigger = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I can draw lines that show the waypoints paths in the Scene window doing it in the DrawLinesInScene function.

But now i want to draw this lines in the game window while the game is running. To make some blinking lights on the terrain ground level in two sides so the player will walk between them. Like when a plane is landing in between the lights. This kind of effect.

For example like this red lights: Maybe not blinking but the idea is to show the waypoints paths like this.

[image: lights]

Comment: FYI, there's a game-development Stack Exchange site [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com). You may get a better answer there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a `LineDrawer` helper class that replaces `Debug.DrawLine` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42819905/3785314) post. It works in the GameView. It has the-same parameter as `Debug.DrawLine` and there is an example of how to use it on that post too. You may have to increase the width of the line.

Simply drawing a line isn't enough since there is a night and you need a GameObject and a light for that. You need to position GameObjects across that line too.

Assuming that this is a straight line, you can convert the path into chuck paths with the function below:

```
void posToChunkDistances(Vector3 from, Vector3 to, Vector3[] result, int chunkAmount)
{
    //divider must be between 0 and 1
    float divider = 1f / chunkAmount;
    float linear = 0f;

    if (chunkAmount == 0)
    {
        Debug.LogError("chunkAmount Distance must be > 0 instead of " + chunkAmount);
        return;
    }

    if (chunkAmount == 1)
    {
        result[0] = Vector3.Lerp(from, to, 0.5f); //Return half/middle point
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < chunkAmount; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            linear = divider / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            linear += divider; //Add the divider to it to get the next distance
        }
        // Debug.Log("Loop " + i + ", is " + linear);
        result[i] = Vector3.Lerp(from, to, linear);
    }
}
```

With this function, you can instantiate 20 GameObjects with a Shape of a light(3D Mesh) and baked lights across the line evenly. This should be a prefab.

```
public GameObject lightPrefab;

void Start()
{
    const int lightCount = 20;
    Vector3[] lightPositions = new Vector3[lightCount];
    posToChunkDistances(waypoints[0].transform.position, waypoints[waypoints.Length-1].transform.position , lightPositions, lightCount);

    for (int i = 0; i < lightPositions.Length; i++)
    {
        Instantiate(lightPrefab, lightPositions[i], Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

You also need to [Lens Flares](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/5) to get the effects from the image in your question.